# Automatic S# column when using filter/query in google sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, array-formulas

Here what i am trying to do
I want to automatically generate the serial number in the column while filtering. i tried to use below formula

```
=SUBTOTAL(3,$B$1:B)-1
```

Which is perfectly working for individually entered data.
but I want to apply the same function on a different sheet which is getting data by query formula and filtering it by different dropdowns.

[image: wanted to add serial number in "A" in sequence]

Comment: I cannot understand about `I want to apply the same function on a different sheet which is getting data by query formula and filtering it by different dropdowns.`. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal?

Comment: Please post the formula you have tried not as a picture. See [how-to-ask-a-good-question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @tanaike in simple words I want to put serial numbers in column A in the attached picture according to the shown result in column B.

Comment: @aerials already posted the formula sir not picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

oK I FIGURED IT OUT
i put 1 in the 1st raw of my data and put below formula to count as per shown results.

```
=IF(ISBLANK(B12),"",A11+1)
```

Thanks